# Yii2: migrations do not apply

Tags: yii2, database-migration

I run `./yii migrate` and get

```
No new migrations found. Your system is up-to-date.
```

I have installed Yii2-usuario and the first time when running `./yii migrate` all migrations are being applied correctly:

```
Yii Migration Tool (based on Yii v2.0.32)

Total 12 new migrations to be applied:
    Da\User\Migration\m000000_000001_create_user_table
    Da\User\Migration\m000000_000002_create_profile_table
    Da\User\Migration\m000000_000003_create_social_account_table
    Da\User\Migration\m000000_000004_create_token_table
    Da\User\Migration\m000000_000005_add_last_login_at
    Da\User\Migration\m000000_000006_add_two_factor_fields
    Da\User\Migration\m000000_000007_enable_password_expiration
    Da\User\Migration\m000000_000008_add_last_login_ip
    Da\User\Migration\m000000_000009_add_gdpr_consent_fields
    m140506_102106_rbac_init
    m170907_052038_rbac_add_index_on_auth_assignment_user_id
    m180523_151638_rbac_updates_indexes_without_prefix

Apply the above migrations? (yes|no) [no]:yes
```

But my migrations in `./migrations` are not found by `./yii migrate`:

```
m20200228_000000_user.php
```

The file starts with and should work:

```
use yii\db\Migration;

class m20200228_000000_user extends Migration
{
    public function safeUp()
...
```

In `./config/web.php` this is configured:

```
'controllerMap' => [
        'migrate' => [
            'class' => \yii\console\controllers\MigrateController::class,
            'migrationPath' => [
                '@app/migrations',
                '@yii/rbac/migrations', // Just in case you forgot to run it on console (see next note)
            ],
            'migrationNamespaces' => [
                'Da\User\Migration',
            ],
        ],
    ],
    ...
```

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31476398/yii2-migrations-not-applying) does not help since migrations ingeneral seem to work here.

What is going on here? Why are my migrations not found at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.

The names of the migration files were wrong, e.g. `m20200228_000000_user.php`.

The name format is `mYYMMDD_XXXXXX.php`.

I had specified a 4-digit year.